# How to convert .mp4 video file to .yuv (YUV420) and vice-versa using FFmpeg and subprocess module in python?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, mp4, yuv

I have to convert a .mp4 video file to .yuv (YUV420) and vice versa in my python program. How do you do this using FFmpeg and subprocess module in python?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from subprocess import Popen

# create command to use ffmpeg to convert mp4 to yuv
cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'video.mp4','video.yuv']
# execute command in "shell"
process = Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Explaination in code comment.

Make sure FFMPEG is added to your system PATH or else call by its path i.e.

```
from subprocess import Popen

# create command to use ffmpeg to convert mp4 to yuv
cmd = ['C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg', '-i', 'video.mp4','video.yuv']
# execute command in "shell"
process = Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

As @llogan mentioned to convert from yuv to mp4 use:

```
cmd = ['ffmpeg', '-video_size', '1280x720', '-pixel_format', 'yuv420p', '-framerate', '25', '-i', 'video.yuv', 'output.mp4']
```

Comment: You forgot the "vice-versa" requirement in the question which would be something like: `ffmpeg -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format yuv420p -framerate 25 -i input.yuv output.mp4`